# In Eclipse, why is it telling me to add in a semi-colon that is already there?

Tags: java, error-messaging

I am working on a very basic game. It's entirely text. It sounds very simple, but as I was declaring the function for confirming the player's username, I was presented with this error message.
[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/duS9O.png)
'Syntax error, insert ";" to complete LocalVariableDeclarationStatement'
Here is the code:

`static void confirmation(); {`

As you can see, it has a semi-colon so why is there an error message telling me to add one?
I have also noticed that it mentions a 'LocalVariableDeclarationStatement' which I have not mentioned any where in my code.

**Note:** I don't actually know what a 'LocalVariableDeclarationStatement' does so it could very well make sense.

Comment: I cannot explain why Eclipse displays this error message but I can tell you that you must remove that semicolon.

Comment: Thats what I did originally but it said to add the samicolon

Answer (score 5):

The compiler thinks that you want to declare a local variable; to do that, you need to insert the semicolon earlier, like this:

```
static void confirmation;
```

However, you can't declare variables of type `void`, so that would not make sense either. If you had used `int` instead of `void`, it would have made more sense.

But it appears that you actually wanted to declare a method, not a local variable. In that case, you need to remove the semicolon altogether:

```
static void confirmation() {
    // method body
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What I find strange is that eclipse is suggesting to add a semicolon where in fact it should say (or suggest you) to add a body

[image] Please ignore the 'abstract line'

In terms of the actual issue as it's been already pointed out you can not have a void variable that's for a start. Secondly, when declaring a method (which can be void) in the modifier you should not have a semicolon at the end of the parameter list as it's invalid syntax.

Comment: I didn't originaly put a semi-colon. It was telling me to, but when I did, it still told me to.

Comment: What happens when you close the project then reopen it? - Eclipse tends to be buggy with syntax